# React Table Disable carrot If no data in sub-component?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using [react table version 6](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table) and I am looking at the built in sub component carrot that allows you to show more information of the row.

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/archives/v6-examples/react-table-sub-components

Though none of the examples show how to disable it on a per row basis, for instance some of my data my not have any sub component row and I don't want to show the carrot if nothing is there.

Comment: you can put check if data is not there return null instead of your custom component.

Answer (score 0):

React table is very highly customizable so I guess you have many options.

1 of them would be using a combination of CSS and JS for eg:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlk7o05844